# EF 4.1: Cannot Add Collection - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: ef-code-first

I was told by JL herself I needed to disable lazy loading and remove virtuals from my code, so:

I. The Domain:

```
    public class Parent
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
    }

    public class Child
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int FK_ParentId { get; set; }            

        [ForeignKey("FK_ParentId")]
        public Parent Parent { get; set; }
    }
```

II. DAL:

```
   public DataContext()
   {
      this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
   }
```

III. program.cs

```
        var clientSvc = new ClientSvcRef.ServiceClient();            
        var parent = new Parent();
        var child = new Child {Parent = parent};
        parent.Children.Add(child);
        clientSvc.AddParent(parent);
```

The problem: Line 4 in program.cs: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: the error comes because your Children Attribut is null you can't add there something "parent.Children = new List<Child>();"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are at least two ways to deal with this issue:

(1) initialize collection yourself in the constructor,

```
public Parent() {
    Children = new List<Child>();
}
```

or (2) use `Create()` instead of `new`:

```
var p = _db.Parents.Create();
var c = _db.Children.Create();
c.Parent = p;
```

Comment: Thanks das, #1 worked. I can't use #2 since I am using WCF. For anyone else using WCF in this scenario, be sure Parent class has attribute [DataContract(IsReference = true)]